# Bash: kill with pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

Trying to `kill` very process related to Java. Is there a way to use pipe for it? I have tried

```
ps -e|grep "java"|kill
```

and

```
ps -e|grep "java"|xargs kill
```

Neither works.

Comment: I cannot easily test this, but I think you should isolate the process number. Something like `ps -e|grep "java"| awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill`.

Comment: Tested it. And ps -e|grep "java"| awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill is the answer I was originally looking

Comment: possible duplicate of [Killing linux process by piping the id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570999/killing-linux-process-by-piping-the-id)

Comment: Worth noting that `killall` and other ways to kill all processes with that name may cause unwanted behavior, so use with caution.

Answer (score 14):

[pgrep](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1//pgrep/) is the right tool for grepping processes:

```
kill $(pgrep -f java)
```

the `-f` flag in [pgrep](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1//pgrep/) is for matching against the full command line used to execute a process.

Comment: Good point re `pgrep`, but since the intent is to *kill*, why not use its cousin, `pkill`, directly?

Comment: Thank you. Both of them work. I did not know pkill/pgrep before

Answer (score 6):

There is, but this is easier (presuming your system has `killall`):

```
killall java
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pkill java`. `pkill` is `pgrep` and `kill` combined into one command.