# Killing linux process by piping the id

Tags: linux, pipe, kill

I want to kill a process and I get its id with:

```
pgrep -f "python myscript.py"
```

I would like to call

```
kill -s SIGINT
```

on it, but I can't find any way to do it.

(the command needs to be in one line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the backtick operator for evaluating a sub-command

```
kill -s SIGINT `pgrep -f "python myscript.py"`
```

(untested)

Comment: Mr. Spuratic makes a good point about how roundabout this actually is.   I was not sitting in front of a Linux system when I wrote it, so stuck with generic *nix-isms rather than details of the particular tools.

Answer (score 4):

Read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill), `pgrep` and `pkill` *are the same program*. Use `pkill` to send a signal to one or more processes which you can select in the same way as `pgrep`.

```
pkill -INT -f "python myscript.py"
```

See also [this question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27087/finding-the-id-of-a-process-and-killing-it) on unix.se (where this question would be a better fit).

Answer (score 3):

It's generally most convenient to use `xargs` to pass data from a pipe as arguments to a command that doesn't read data from `stdin` themselves:

```
pgrep -f "python myscript.py" | xargs kill -s SIGINT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also kill a process by name

> killall -s SIGINT processname