# How to feed the output of one pipe to another pipe?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a command here:

```
ps aux | grep -i java | grep -i test | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

which gives only one process id like `1201`. Now I want to kill them by piping the `1201` to `kill` command.

How do I do that?

I tried `tee` like this:

```
ps aux | grep -i java | grep -i test | awk '{ print $2 }' | tee >(kill -9)
```

but that gives:

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

where I'm making mistake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Killing linux process by piping the id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570999/killing-linux-process-by-piping-the-id)

Comment: The literal answer to your question is `xargs`, but instead of using this pipe construct you will want to use e.g. `pkill`.

Comment: `pkill` ? What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xargs to convert standard input to command-line parameters

```
ps aux | grep -i java | grep -i test | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill
```

Comment: Also, lose the `grep | grep | awk` -- you can trivially refactor this to a single Awk script.